# can anyone recommend a firefox plugin so I can see exactly what is being sent to a post form?

Tags: debugging, forms, post, firefox-addon

I'm trying to debug my form POST code. Is there any firefox plugin so I can see exactly what the browser is sending (rather than monitor at the server side)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)? It lets you see HTTP requests and responses on the 'net' tab.

Comment: +1, Firebug is exactly what you need to see 'under the hood' like this.

Answer (score 4):

[Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829)

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) works with IE, Firefox, and many other processes.

Answer (score 2):

try charles, you can monitor IE and FF.  Tamper data should also work well

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966

Answer (score 1):

[Get Firebug!](http://getfirebug.com/), it has everything you need -- or alternatively [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/3829).

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgetfirebug.com%2F&ei=QhRGS5HNO8qQtgefpfXtAQ&usg=AFQjCNGT1rhhsYGPQx5Vr5A8RvhIgdSp9g&sig2=IwODw829QTHgc0fr2Z49gQ) can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug and in the network tab see what is posted [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1843)

Answer (score 0):

There's also HTTP Analyzer